# Equations of motion from the Standard Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model

For some time now I have been wondering if you could not derive any sort of equations of motion from the Standard Model:

$$\mathscr{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+i\bar{\psi}D\psi+\bar{\psi}\phi\psi+h.c.+\vert D\phi\vert^2-V(\phi).$$

Since it is a Lagrangian shouldn't we be able to use the Euler-Lagrange equation to find some equations of motion? Since I don't understand the theory myself this might already have been done, or is being done by physicists. However that does not impact my curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a normal field theory, so you may derive the equations of motion. They will be the ordinary Maxwell's equations for the electromagnetic field
$$ \partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu} = j^\nu $$
with $j^\mu$ calculated as the sum of the conserved currents for the Dirac field and for the Higgs fields, combined with the Dirac equation coupled to the electromagnetic field (with some Yukawa interaction $y\cdot \phi\psi$ terms), and the Klein-Gordon equation for a charged scalar field with some $V'(\phi)$ and $\psi \psi$ terms added in the right hand side etc.

Comment: Hello. May I ask: Can we use these equations of motion( not necessarily of the SM but even of a simpler theory like $\phi ^4 $ ) for any calculation with non-perturbing methods or for the examination of bound states? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the theories in principle know about all physical objects, phenomena, and quantities, including bound states, but it may be hard to perform the complete quantum calculation. Whether an exact quantum calculation is possible in principle depends on the theory. Even the simple $\phi^4$ theory is perturbatively OK and renormalizable to all orders. But it is inconsistent beyond perturbative expansions. The coupling "runs" and diverges at some exponentially high energy scale - develops the "Landau pole" which prevents everyone from computing extremely high-energy phenomena.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If you only allow me one last question: Why is it so difficult to speak of bound states in QFT and why not use the equations of motion to get results of bound states as we do with non relativistic SE. Thanks, again. Any introductory references or previews about bound states and QFT are welcomed if you can spare the time.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack, the bound states are much harder in the fully relativistic regime - in QFT where non-relativistic etc. approximations can't be trusted - because the interactions are heavily nonlinear and more importantly, with enough speed/energy in QFT, particle-antiparticle pairs are created out of pure energy and disappearing again. That's why you need supercomputers to simulate e.g. protons - bound states in QCD. The computers really simulate every point in space/lattice and describe the most general, very complicated wave functionals for the bound states.

Comment: In the bound states that arise from QFT, even the number of particles is in a heavy superposition of all conceivable choices. Protons have lots of gluons and quark-antiquark pairs in them - in some sense virtual particles except that you can catch them if you measure the particle content at a given time. So the right question is why the non-relativistic treatment is easy. It's because e.g. in the hydrogen atom, the speed is $v/c\sim\alpha$, the fine-structure constant, so non-relativistic. Therefore not enough energy to create pairs etc. And that's also why the potential is $\sim 1/r$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  The Euler-Lagrange equations are found by minimizing the action with respect to small fluctuations in the fields.  For details look at the Relativistic Field Theory section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_field_theory.  Note though that the resultant equations are usually not referred to as "equations of motion" since you are minimizing with respect to fields and not paths.

The minimization leads to many useful equations in QFT, for example the Klein-Gordon equation and the Dirac equation, depending on the Lagrangian.

Comment: Hello. May I ask: Can we use these equations of motion( not necessarily of the SM but even of a simpler theory like $\phi ^4 $ ) for any calculation with non-perturbing methods or for the examination of bound states? Thank you.